# Разобраться в объектах gtk и их иерархии

Tags: c, gtk

На протяжении полугода изучал Си и теперь приступил к изучению GTK. У меня возникли вопросы, на которые я пока что не смог найти ответа.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что объекты в gtk (например GtkWidget) являются по факту обычной структурой?
2. Как понять "иерархия объектов"? Например GtkWidget > GtkContainer > GtkBin > GtkWindow. Значит ли это, что GTKWindow включает в себя все элементы структуры GtkBin и имеет еще свои уникальные? То есть это выглядит примерно так:

```
    struct GtkWindow {
        уникальные для GtkWindow элементы структуры;
        struct GtkBin _GtkBin
    };
```

A GtkBin в свою очередь так:

```
    struct GtkBin {
        уникальные для GtkBin элементы структуры;
        struct GtkContainer _GtkContainer
    };
```

И так далее или как это реализовано?

3. Почему при создании нового окна с помощью gtk_window_new возвращается указатель на виджет, а не на окно? Ведь в gtk есть специальный объект для этого.
4. Что происходит при преобразовании в другой тип с помощью макросов например так: GTK_WINDOW(mainwin). Создается новая срктура, в которую добавляются новые элементы, если mainwin это GtkWidget?

Answer (score 2):

1. да, это структуры Простые обычные структуры. Просто оформлены по определенным правилам.
2. Не нужно гадать, можно посмотреть в исходники.

   ```
   struct _GtkWindow
   {
      GtkBin bin;

      GtkWindowPrivate *priv;
   };
   ```

   только "базовая структура" указывается самой первой, что бы легко подсовывать "структуру наследника" там, где можно написать "родительскую структуру" (я специально в кавычки взял).
3. Честно не знаю, но думаю, что это такое соглашение. Хотя мне кажется, так легче было сделать многие функции - они получают указатель на "базовую структуру" и типы сходятся. А кому нужно - вверх подымет.
4. Обычный каст. Правда там ещё может быть и дополнительная проверка, что объект валидный. Опять же, можно посмотреть в сорцы

   ```
    #define GTK_WINDOW(obj)     (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), GTK_TYPE_WINDOW, GtkWindow))
    #define G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST(instance, g_type, c_type)    (_G_TYPE_CIC ((instance), (g_type), c_type))

    /* --- implementation bits --- */
    #ifndef G_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS
    #  define _G_TYPE_CIC(ip, gt, ct) \
        ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
    #  define _G_TYPE_CCC(cp, gt, ct) \
        ((ct*) g_type_check_class_cast ((GTypeClass*) cp, gt))
    #else /* G_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS */
    #  define _G_TYPE_CIC(ip, gt, ct)       ((ct*) ip)
    #  define _G_TYPE_CCC(cp, gt, ct)       ((ct*) cp)
    #endif /* G_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS */
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только я не понял ваше объяснение ко второму вопросу про родительские структуры, структуры наследника и т.д. 4. Как понять "обычный каст"? Если мы преобразуем из char в int, то в образовавшиеся биты записываются нули. А если из float в int, то дробная часть отбрасывается. т.е. часть информации теряется. Происходит ли здесь что-то подобное или это какие-то формальные изменения? В доках посмотрел про макрос G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST. Там написано: ...Returns instance casted to a pointer to c_type. К сожалению, мне это ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: когда происходит каст указателя одного типа на указатель другого типа, но на низком уровне ничего не происходит (мы говорим о си!). И если есть структура `A`, и структура `B`, где первым членом идет переменная типа `A`, то  по указателю их первые `sizof(A)` будут одинаковые по сути и можно использовать указатель на `B` везде, где можно использовать указатель на `A`.